# using python extract data from xml having xmlns namespace

Tags: python, xml, namespaces

I have an XML having namespace as:

```
<metadata xmlns="http://example.com">


<samples>
<sample>

    <hashes>
        <hash type="md5">Abc6FC6F4AA4C5315D2A52E29865F7F6</hash>
    </hashes>


    <detections>

        <detection vendor="example_1" date="2015-02-17T01:55:38" type="human" >

            <![CDATA[my_detection1]]>

        </detection>

        <detection vendor="example_2" date="2015-02-17T01:55:38" type="computer" >

            <![CDATA[my_detection2]]>


        </detection>

    </detections>
</sample>

<sample>

    <hashes>
        <hash type="md5">CDEFC6F4AA4C5315D2A52E29865F7F6</hash>
    </hashes>


    <detections>

        <detection vendor="example_3" date="2015-02-17T01:55:38" type="human" >

              <![CDATA[my_detection3]]>

        </detection>

        <detection vendor="example_4" date="2015-02-17T01:55:38" type="computer" >

              <![CDATA[my_detection4]]>

        </detection>

    </detections>
</sample>
</samples>
</metadata>
```

I want to extract data such that:

If a particular "md5" matches then check the "vendor" attribute in "detection" and if that matches then extract attribute "date" and text value (e.g.:"my_detection1")

The file will be very large containing a lots of "sample" tags. Thanks.

Comment: What do the md5 hashes need to match?  Do you have a set of md5 hashes already in memory via some other means?

Comment: Yes Pete ! I'll be making a function call with a parameter having a value for md5.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All ! Finally I found how to achieve this.
DOM in python is best for doing difficult XML operations which requires lot of if/else kind of operations:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import Node

dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("C:/tmp/merged.xml")

hash_node=dom.getElementsByTagName('hash')

md5='7CD6FC6F4AA4C5315D2A52E29865F7F6'

for node1 in hash_node:

    str1 = node1.childNodes[0].wholeText

    if (str1 == md5):

        hashes_node = node1.parentNode
        sample_node = hashes_node.parentNode
        detection_node = sample_node.getElementsByTagName('detection')


        print ("For MD5 " + md5 + ",\n\n")
        for node2 in detection_node:

            print (node2.childNodes[0].wholeText)
```